# Issue with getSharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I can't obtain data from `SharedPreferences`.. After I click on a button, it executes `AsyncTask` in a different class named `Background`.

```
public class Background extends AsyncTask<Integer,Void,String>{

    private Context context;
    private AsyncResponse listener;

    public Background(Context context,AsyncResponse listener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listener=listener;
    }
```

`AsyncResponse` is an interface that I've created to inform my `MainMactivity` that background work has been finished. It's just:

```
package com.example.pablo.zad3;

public interface AsyncResponse {
    void TaskCompleted();
}
```

Then I want to pass the result to `SharedPreferences`:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        SharedPreferences prefs = this.context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        prefs.edit().putString("A", s);
        prefs.edit().commit();

        listener.TaskCompleted();
    }
```

But in my `MainActivity` I can't get the resulting string, it's like there was no `A` key in `SharedPreferences` (I always get `"NO DATA"`):

```
 @Override
    public void TaskCompleted() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(prefs != null) {
            String text = prefs.getString("A", "NO DATA");
            editText2.setText(text);
        }
    }
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, can u help me?

Comment: @JaiminModi there is no such option to choose.

Comment: dobre: `prefs.edit().putString("A", s);
        prefs.edit().commit();` heheeh ... tak na chłopski rozum ... edit - odczyt ... comit - zapis ... jeśli zrobiłeś odczyt - zmiana  ... a potem odczyt - zapis ... to co tam bedzie? ... raczej powinno być odczyt - zmiana - zapis

Comment: @Selvin Dziękuję Ci bardzo:) wiem, że dla Ciebie to błahostka, ale ja jestem całkiem nowy zarówno w Javie, jak i Androidzie. Myślałem, że to ta taki sam wynik, jak gdybym napisał `SharedPreferences prefs.Editor = this.context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();`. Dodaj swoja podpowiedź jako odpowiedź, to był właśnie problem:)

Comment: `putString(...)` string returns `SP.Editor` ... so you can chain ... like `prefs.edit().putString("A", s).putXXX(...).putXXX(...).commit();`

Comment: still, the question is: **do you need a SP for this at all?** ... you can easily change the `AsyncResponse` interface and pass it via `TaskCompleted` parameter ...

Comment: @Selvin It is my task to use `SP`. Normally, I'd use parameters as with delegates. I was wondering about is there any way so that my `MainActivity` could be notified after `OnPostExecute()` without `interface`? For instance so that I could handle this in some `OnSth()` of `MainActivity`?

Comment: no, it will be allways some kind of interface ... as in strongly typed languages you have to had some contract ... but you can use other interfaces ... like BroadcastReceiver with localbroadcastmanager ... or other event bus implementation ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem are those two lines:

```
    prefs.edit().putString("A", s);
    prefs.edit().commit();
```

at the first one you are opening SharedPreferences for edit and do the changes ...

now at the second line you are opening it again ... which causing the previous changes rollback ...

As the "family" of `putXXX(...)` method of the `SharedPreferences.Editor` class returns Editor itself you should do something like:

```
    prefs.edit().putString("A", s).putXXX(...).putXXX(...).commit();
```

(by `putXXX(...)` I mean puting other preferences fx `putInt("Z", 666)`)

now the changes will be saved

Answer (score 0):

Use this for writing to preferences:

```
//Write to preferences
        String s = "this is a test.";
        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs",this.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("A", s);
        editor.apply();
```

And this for retrieving information

```
//Fetch from preferences
        SharedPreferences prefs2 = this.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", this.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(prefs2 != null) {
            String text2 = prefs.getString("A","");
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "This is the string: "+text2);
        }
```

The only thing that you missed is an editor.